# How to copy this section of a webpage when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to copy a section of a webpage when a link is clicked so that the section is recreated underneath the previous section just like how this works in this image as example- [image]

I'm doing this on google apps script and here is my code

**code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('HTML')
        .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

**HTML.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">

    <style type="text/css">
        .contentBackground {
            background-color: #D8D8D8;
            clear: left;
            width: 60%;
            margin: auto;
            height: 200px display: block;
        }

        .uploadFile p {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 20px;
            color: red;
        }

        .content p {
            text-align: center;
            color: red;
            padding: 7px;
        }

        .dropDown p {
            text-align: center;
            padding: 40px;
            margin-left: 8px;
            height:;
        }

        .moreFiles {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="contentBackground">
        <div class="uploadWrapper">
            <div class="fileUpload">
                <div class="uploadFile">
                    <p>Upload File: <span style="color:black"><input type="file" name="uploadField" /></span></p>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <p>Width(Inch) <input type="text" style="width: 100px"> Height(Inch) <input type="text" style="width: 100px"> Quantity <input type="text" style="width: 100px"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="dropDown">
            <p>
                Material <select style="max-width: 10%;">
                    <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
                    <option value="Vinyl Banner">Vinyl Banner</option>
                    <option value="Adhesive Vinyl">Adhesive Vinyl</option>
                    <option value="Polygloss">Polygloss</option>
                    <option value="Translucent Vinyl">Translucent Vinyl</option>
                    <option value="Static Cling Clear">Static Cling Clear</option>
                    <option value="Static Cling White">Static Cling White</option>
                    <option value="Reverse Static Cling">Reverse Static Cling</option>
                    <option value="Outdoor Paper">Outdoor Paper</option>
                    <option value="Backlit Film">Backlit Film</option>
                    <option value="Foam">Foam</option>
                    <option value="Coroplast">Coroplast</option>
                    <option value="Corrugated Board">Corrugated Board</option>
                    <option value="Sintra">Sintra</option>
                    <option value="Canvas">Canvas</option>
                    <option value="Fabric">Fabric</option>
                    <option value="All Cling">All Cling</option>
                </select>
                Lamination <select>
                    <option value="None">None</option>
                    <option value="Matte">Matte</option>
                    <option value="Gloss">Gloss</option>
                    <option value="Lexan">Lexan</option>
                    <option value="Erasable">Erasable</option>
                </select>
                Mounting <select>
                    <option value="3/16&quot Foam">3/16" Foam</option>
                    <option value="3/16&quot Gator">3/16" Gator</option>
                    <option value="1/8&quot Sintra">1/8" Sintra</option>
                    <option value="24point Card">24point Card</option>
                    <option value="50point Card">50point Card</option>
                    <option value="Adhesive Back">Adhesive Back</option>
                    <option value="MDF">MDF</option>
                    <option value="Coroplast">Coroplast</option>
                    <option value="Masonite">Masonite</option>
                    <option value="020 Styrene">020 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="040 Styrene">040 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="060 Styrene">060 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="080 Styrene">080 Styrene</option>
                    <option value="Corrugated Board">Corrugated Board</option>
                </select>
                Ink <select>
                    <option value="Indoor">Indoor</option>
                    <option value="Outdoor">Outdoor</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="moreFiles">
        <a href="#" id="add">Add another file?</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: generally you don't want to use head body and html tags in google apps script. if you need to add things to the head append them to the head using javascript.  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#dont_use_html_head_or_body_tags

Comment: ok thanks for the heads up!

Comment: yeah their caja filter/processor can mess things up if you don't follow the best practices guide.

Comment: so basically anything that I do with style should be done in the java script?

Comment: no you can put style tag in the body

Comment: thank you so much! this helped me solve the problem i was having below !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you opt to use jQuery, then you can use the [`.clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) method.

```
$("#add").on("click", function () {
     var $last = $(".contentBackground").last();
     $last.clone().insertAfter($last);
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/clarketm/z0sobj24/)

Comment: how do i add jQuery to google app script? when I switch out what i have in code.gs for what you recommended it gives me an error that says : ReferenceError: "$" is not defined. (line 1, file "")

Comment: @Kali - I found this resource from [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#take_advantage_of_jquery). You just need to include the jQuery library. e.g. `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: would I add it to my code.gs section or in my .html section?

Comment: i've added `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
$("#add").on("click", function () {
    var $last = $(".contentBackground").last();
    $last.clone().insertAfter($last);
});
</script>` to my webpage but all it does is sends the page to a new url and blanks it

Comment: @Kali - do you have a link to the webpage?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96288/discussion-between-travis-clarke-and-kali).

Comment: it's google apps script so i don't know if this'll work but here you go : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwSQiydw6syaabKpQP6yXUtEOKF0tBcoxJGf1O4-Xc/dev